# Java String to Date Conversion Issue

Tags: java, datetime

I searched this issue but found only changing from String to Date and then displaying Date to String. 
        I have a requirement, where I receive Date in String format and then I have to parse that in Date object and enter in Database.But whenever I convert String to Date it gives me wrong output. Please suggest. thanks in advance.

```
String subscribedDate="2012-09-28 11:00:00";
String oldFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss";
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat(oldFormat);
Date dates=sdf1.parse(subscribedDate);
System.out.println(dates);
//code for entering dates in database.
```

Output:
Sat Jan 28 00:09:00 GMT 2012   (Which is incorrect!!).  I want as  2012-09-28  11:00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the oldFormat variable in the second line should be

```
oldFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"; // hours counted 0~23
```

or

```
oldFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"; // hours counted 0~11
```

Answer (score 6):

Your format string is wrong.  `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` is basically saying "years-miniutes-days hours:minutes:seconds" which I'm pretty sure you don't want.

You want

```
String oldFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
```

Have a look at the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) docs for more info

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the month field is represented using `MM` and not `mm` which is for minutes.

Secondly, the formatter can be used to print the date in the desired format.

```
String subscribedDate="2012-09-28 11:00:00";
String oldFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat(oldFormat);
Date dates=sdf1.parse(subscribedDate);
System.out.println(sdf1.format(dates));
// code for entering dates in database.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change oldFormat to

```
String oldFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
```

where MM are capital letters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        String oldFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
```

See the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to find out why.